# TensorFlow optimization proceeds non-deterministically on GPU

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I'm using Google TensorFlow to fit a small, 2-layer net. I've noticed that when I use a GPU with AdamOptimizer or RMSPropOptimizer, the optimization proceeds non-deterministically. Even if I seed the graph with set_random_seed, the opt produces substantially different weights each time.

The problem does not occur if I use other optimizers (e.g. GradientDescentOptimizer) or configure the graph to run on a CPU.

Has anyone encountered similar behavior in TensorFlow or have any ideas on debugging the problem?

I'm using TensorFlow 0.7.1 with a Nvidia Grid K520 GPU.

Comment: what if you create session with config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still produces different results every time even with that config.

Comment: I have seen slight differences on GPU (ie, after 100 steps of MNIST the loss is off by .001) from previous run, but haven't dug deep

Comment: Have you come across any updates / more information? I am also experiencing a similar effect.

Comment: Hi @DFM, did you figure this out. I am having the same problem